# How to use 2 CSS files in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm new to Webpack and have installed `"webpack": "^3.5.5"` package. Here is my webpack.config.js.

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```

It works fine for one CSS file, but i would like to load 2 CSS files. 
1- Bootstrap 
2- style.css

I tried some configuration that i found on Github, but it didn't help. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading of the css file is done via importing them from a js file. So if you want to use the file 'style.css', import it from a js file like:

```
import './style.css';
```

Then webpack will use the css loader to bring in your styles.

Comment: I have done this. But it doesn't load both. I used require for both and it loads only one which stays above.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are including bootstrap. With bootstrap, you probably just want to use a link tag in the head if the html file to bring it in. If you actually want to bring it in via webpack, you have to import it in the same way and reference the main css file wherever it lives. If it's in node_modules, you don't need a whole path, webpack will default to looking there.